# Would it be better to convert my console-based game to a Tkinter GUI before or after adding the ability to save scores?

Tags: python, excel, user-interface, tkinter

I have created a number guessing game in Python. I created it as a command-line application, because at the time that was all I knew how to do. I now know that it's possible to make a GUI application using Tkinter, so I would like to convert my program to a GUI application. Will this require re-coding everything? My second question is, I am interesting in being able to add the function to save/recall high scores and whatnot from an Excel spreadsheet using xlwt and xlrd. My question here is, would it make more sense to convert to a GUI application first, or to add all the main features (ie Excel spreadsheets) before re-coding everything to be a Tkinter program?

```
 ## Author: Ethan Houston
## Name: NumberGame
## Date: 07/19/2015

"""
Features to add:
    -Profiles system

    -Save high scores to spreadsheet

    -(COMPLETED) Different response based on how far off user's guess is (WIP code included)  

    -Make scoring system better (make fairer for higher difficulties)       

        -Custom difficulty modifier
"""

import random

import timeit

import xlwt

import xlrd

print "\nWelcome to Ethan's Number Guessing Game!"

"""print "New or existing user?\n1. Existing\n2. New"
user = input()
## User chooses new profile or use an existing one

if user == 1:
    name = raw_input("Enter user name: ")
    ## Figure out how to read file
    pass
if user == 2: 
    newname = raw_input("What is your name?: ")
    sheet1.write(1, 0, str(newname))
    book.save("NumberGame.xls")
    """
while True:
    print "What would you like to do?: \n1. Play game\n2. View High Scores\n3. View Credits"
    menudec = input()
    ## menudec is Menu Decision

    if menudec == 1:
        difficulty = input("Pick a difficulty!: \n1: Easy\n2: Medium\n3: Hard\n4: Insane\n5. Out of control!\n6. Custom\n")         
        ## Chooses difficulty based on number          
        ## Difficulty '0' is diagnostic mode
        if difficulty == 1:
            level = 10
            difmod = 1

        elif difficulty == 2:
            level = 50
            difmod = 1.5

        elif difficulty == 3:
            level = 100 
            difmod = 2

        elif difficulty == 4:
            level = 1000  
            difmod = 10

        elif difficulty == 5:
            level = 10000  
            difmod = 20

        elif difficulty == 6:
            print "What would you like to highest number to be?: "
            level = input()  
            if level > 10:
                difmod = 0.5
            elif level >= 10:
                difmod = 1
            elif level >= 100000:  
                difmod = 50
            else:
                difmod = 10
            ## Need to figure out a better way to calculate difficulty modifier

        elif difficulty == 0:
            level = 1
            difmod = 1
        ## level chooses the range of numbers to guess from
        ## difmod is difficulty modifier, making score higher for harder difficulties

        else:
            print "Not a valid choice!"
            break
        """ FIGURE OUT HOW TO EXPAND MULTIPLE LINES"""
        ## Exits program if you don't choose a difficulty

        number = random.randint(1, level)
        ## Generates random number based off of difficulty level
        print number
        guess = input("Guess a number between 1 and " + str(level) + "!: ")
        ## Takes input from user

        tries = 1
        ## Counter for number of attempts at guessing

        while guess > level:
           guess = input("Above range!\nMake sure to guess between 1 and " + str(level) + "!: ")
        ## If the user chooses a number above the range, makes you try again until within range

        startTime = timeit.default_timer()
        ## Starts a timer once first valid number is selected

        while guess != number:
        ## While loop that runs as long as guess isn't correct
            if guess > number:
                if guess - number <= level * 0.1:
                    guess = input("Too high, close!: ")
                    tries += 1
                    ## If difference between guess and answer is less than or equal to 10% of level,
                    ## prints different prompt
                else:
                    guess = input("Too high, guess again: ")
                    tries += 1
                    ## Normal behavior

            elif guess < number:
                if guess - number <= level * 0.1:
                    guess = input("Too low, close!: ")
                    tries += 1
                    ## If difference between guess and answer is less than or equal to 10% of level,
                    ## prints different prompt
                else:
                    guess = input("Too low, guess again: ")
                    tries += 1
                    ## Normal behavior

        endTime = timeit.default_timer()
        ## Takes the time after the correct number is chosen

        totalTime = endTime - startTime
        ## Calculates time difference between start and finish

        print "\nCorrect! It took you " + str(round(totalTime, 2)) + " seconds and " + str(tries) + " tries to guess.\n"
        ## Once user guesses correct number, program tells how many tries it took, and how long

        score = 1/(1+(tries * round(totalTime, 2))) * 1000 * difmod
        ## Calcualtes score, making lower times and fewer tries yield a higher score
        ## Difmod takes into account the difficulty
        ## Multiply by 1000 to make number more readable

        print "Score: " + str(round(score, 2)) + "\n"
        ## Printsthe score, rounded to 1 decimal place

        book = xlrd.open_workbook("NumberGame.xls")



    elif menudec == 2:
        ## Figure out how to access high scores
        print "This feature is currently under development.\n"

    elif menudec == 3:
            print "\nDeveloped by Ethan Houston"
            raw_input()
            print "\nDeveloped in Python 2.7.9 using Sublime Text 2"
            raw_input()
            print "\nThanks for playing :)"
            raw_input()
            ## Simple credits reel. Go me
    else:
    ## Break if a correct option isn't selected
        break
```

Comment: Some things you'll be able to leave as-is, other things you won't. Anything with user interaction (the "view" in MVC) will need to change. Things like stored scores, Excel spreadsheets, and so on (the "model" in MVC) will probably need no changes. As for what controls what gets displayed and calculated (the "controller" in MVC), that depends on whether you have a separate controller or a bunch of control statements sprinkled throughout your code.

Comment: What do you mean here by 'MVC'? I am not familiar with controllers, and don't know if I have a separate one or not, I guess I will have to research control statements too, because I don't know what those are.

Comment: It's just a design pattern. [Use it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) if you want, or don't. I think that as long as you try to keep separate functions separate (like, a function that accepts a filename and saves the game to a file should be separate from a function that pops a dialog box asking the user whether they want to save), you'll have already made a big difference in maintainability.

Comment: Try writing your core functions, like the number generation algorithm, the save function, and so on, then test them from the interpreter or in a test script. When it mostly works, design the interface with dummy functions (as in, "enter S to save" or "click here to save" would just spit out "save function called"). Then connect the core functions to the interface.

Comment: You just need to find a comfortable spot between ease of planning now and ease of debugging/expansion later.

Comment: Thanks! Before I go any further I will do what you said and delegate different parts of the program into their own functions.